# Domain of a function defined with another function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, continuity

Suppose $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}$, and $g(x)=\frac{1}{1+\frac{2}{f(x)}}$. To find the points not in the domain of $g(x)$, we obviously have to check the $x-$values where $f(x)$ becomes $0$ and $-2$, and count them first.

But where is the intuition behind considering the points for which $f(x)$ itself is undefined? On substituting $f(x)$ in $g(x)$, you get $g(x)=\frac{x}{3x+2}$. Why do we count the additional points where $f$ is discontinuous (in this case, the only extra one being $x=-1$, as $x=0$ is already necessary for $g(x)$'s denominator to be defined)?

Comment: It's similar to asking where $x\mapsto\frac xx$ is defined. In this form, it's not defined for $x=0$..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to find when $g$ is undefined and this is when the denominator, $1+ \frac {2}{f(x)} = 0 $ which is only true when $f(x) = -2$. So then we check $-2 = \frac {1}{1+\frac{1}{x}} \implies 1+\frac {1}{x} = -\frac{1}{2}\implies x=-\frac {2}{3}.$ So $g(-\frac{2}{3})$ is not defined and $x = -\frac {2}{3}$ is not in the domain of $g$. Notice that $g$ is also not defined when $f(x) = 0$, but $f(x)$ never equals $0$ so this is not a problem. We must check where $f(x)$ is undefined now. This is when $1+ \frac{1}{x} = 0 \implies x = -1$. so then $g(-1)$ is not defined either. Also $f(0)$ is undefined since $\frac {1}{0}$ is undefined which means $g(0)$ is undefined. Hence the points not in the domain of $g$ are $x = -1, -\frac {2}{3},0$.

Comment: I got the $\frac{-2}{3}$ root, but when you substitute the expression of f(x) in g, you get $g(x) = \frac{x}{3x+2}$. Obviously, -1 is in the domain of this function. But why is g still not defined at -1? Similarly, g(0) is also defined now, so why isn't 0 included in g's domian?

Comment: You can't substitute $f$ until you check where $f$ is undefined.$ f(-1)$ gives $1/0$ so $f$ is undefined at $f(-1) g(-1)$ doesn't make sense as if relies on the undefined value $f(-1)$.

Comment: Okay-can you drop some rules that imply that?

Comment: Because when you substitute $f$, the solutions you get are assuming $f$ is defined everywhere. You are assuming implicitly that $f(x)$ always makes sense. Of course, you can't make this assumption.

Comment: Right, got it. Could you add that to the answer?